# Get sticky head to work on table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have my sticky element built in Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(stickyRelocate);
});

var stickMob = document.getElementById("sticky-mobile");
var stop = (stickMob.offsetTop - 60);

window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop, left.offsetTop);

    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
        stickMob = 'stick';
    } else {
        stickMob.className = '';
    }
}
```

it works unless I apply it to a table.. any idea why its not working?

```
<thead>
     <tr>
          <th><h3>Freebies</h3></th>
          <div id="sticky-mobile">
               <th class="text-centred"><p> Together+ plan</p></th>
               <th class="text-centred"><p> Together plan</p></th>
          </div>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beep1986/vu7bfcwv/)

Comment: Could you post here or via jsfiddle.net the full source of what you're trying to do?

Comment: First off, `<div>`s cant be a child of `<tr>`s. It get's tricky with tables. Essentially you need to create a separate fixed element that duplicates the table header and shows/hides it as the page scrolls.

Comment: i have posted the fiddel above, hope that helps

Comment: You can't use `div` in `tr` . You must put it inside the `th`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your html and javascript.

- make your `sticky-mobile` container a `tr` inside the table (not inside another `tr`.
- what should this do? `stickMob = 'stick';` to add a class use jquery `addClass` method or javascripts `className` property.
- This throws an error `$(window).scroll(stickyRelocate);` because there is no function `stickyRelocate`

After some cleanup this code is a good start:

```
<table> 
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><h3>Freebies</h3></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="sticky-mobile">
    <th class="text-centred"><p> Together+ plan</p></th>
    <th class="text-centred"><p> Together plan</p></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Js:

```
var stickMob = document.getElementById("sticky-mobile");
var stop = stickMob.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;


    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
        stickMob.className = 'stick';
    } else {
        stickMob.className = '';
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with your code cleaned up a little: https://jsfiddle.net/32zfy7rq/1/

Good luck.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. the problem is this is now ticking all the time. i only need it to stick once i have scrolled onto id="sticky-mobile"

Comment: I removed the `-60` for the `stop` variable. It is still jumping a little because  the table row is suddenly `position:fixed;` and thus doesn't consume any space. To prevent that you could create a clone of the row that is sticky, and hide the row itself using `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: Its not jumping, but before hand the header would only become sticky once I scroll past <div id="sticky-mobile"> now its sticky right from the top of the page